# Setting background color of td cell according to selected dropdown

Tags: jquery, css

The code I have :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select onchange="this.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" style="background-color:yellow">One</option>
        <option value="2" style="background-color:red">Two</option>
        <option value="3" style="background-color:green">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now here I can set the background color of options in the drop down box. What I need is to set the background color of  cell with the selected option color.
I searched the Internet pretty much but couldn't find anything similar. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1h3jwnpd/)

Comment: It works on opera, i didn't try it on chrome. but this is not a reason to downvote my post.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for this. What have you tried?

Comment: this is what I found on a link. but it doesn't work. `<select onchange="this.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor"> 
    <option style="background-color:yellow">Item 1</option> 
    <option style="background-color:lightyellow">Item 2</option> 
</select> `

Comment: Why is it being downvoted? I don't understand.

Comment: @Max this community has good people and bad too... i don't understand one thing... do you need to color the <option> cell or the <td> cell?

Comment: @Max I don't know the reason of who downvoted you. I just wrote a comment, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You applied the color to the select element. Instead, you should apply it to the parent of the select element. I added .parentNode to the javascript.

```css
td {
padding: 1rem; /* Just to make the color better visible */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select onchange="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1" style="background-color:yellow">One</option>
        <option value="2" style="background-color:red">Two</option>
        <option value="3" style="background-color:green">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem i have with this solution and the others, it leaves the value in a white box, in a color td cell. What I really need is to set the color of the visible box same color with the selected option. I start to doubt if it's possible.

Comment: It's possible. but someone fixed the code in my post, now it works as i want actually. the solution is in the question.

Comment: @max I adjusted the code. Now both the select and td are colored.

Answer (score 2):

try with `jquery` its working

```js
$('.green').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parent().css('background', $(this).val());
});
```

```css
table tr td {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="green">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="yellow" style="background-color:yellow">One</option>
        <option value="red" style="background-color:red">Two</option>
        <option value="green" style="background-color:green">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 1):

Use **jQuery** to catch `onchange` event of select.

Then, you can get `select` container using `.parent()` (it returns the father element of the one calling it) and set its background-color with the selected value of `select`.

```js
$('select.color-select').change(function(){
  $(this).parent().css({ 'background-color': $(this).val() });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="green color-select">
        <option value="" selected>Select a color</option>
        <option value="yellow" style="background-color:yellow">One</option>
        <option value="red" style="background-color:red">Two</option>
        <option value="green" style="background-color:green">Three</option> 
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Thanks, Rory. i spent quite some time to find a solution before posting.

Comment: Marco, this solution doesn't work when padding is 0.

Comment: Well.. when padding is 0 you did not see the <td> because the <select> is occupying the entire space. But if you inspect the <td> with chrome, you can see its color has changed :) If you don't want to use padding, you can set a width to the table style.